# File conversion .mwb format to .json

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to convert MWB (MYSQL workbench) file into json file using Nodejs, But I didn't find any library or module to parse MWB file, can anybody suggest me how to do it ?

I tried to parse xml2js module to convert but MWB file has not proper xml format that's why it's not working.